# PHP loop problem

Tags: php, loops

On my site I have hundreds of lines of code just like this:

```
<a href="highslide/images/large/08/02IMG_0012.jpg" class="highslide" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/08/03IMG_0020.jpg" class="highslide" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/08/04IMG_0019.jpg" class="highslide" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/08/05IMG_0011.jpg" class="highslide" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
    </a>
```

I was wondering if its possible to use PHP to save me having so many lines of code. Changing the photos filenames to photo1.jpg, photo2.jpg etc would be easy with a batch renamer. I'm just unsure how to implement the PHP cause I'm a bit of a noob. I got somin like this so far:

```
$photo = 1;
$ext = .jpg;

while() {

echo '<a href="highslide/images/large/08/'.$photo.$ext.'" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">';

$photo++

}
```

Comment: The answers here are correct, but there is another approach: looping through the contents of the directory which stores the images. (see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php ). This approach would preclude you having to edit the PHP file every time you upload an image and could handle arbitrary filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although "while" loops will do this, "for" loops are more appropriate for sequential iteration.

```
$photoCount = 10;
$ext = .jpg;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $photoCount; $i++) {
    echo '<a href="highslide/images/large/08/'.$i.$ext.'" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">';
}
```

Comment: That's probably the better solution.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, you just need to add an exit condition in your while loop.
When the loop has to end? When it has printed all the photos. So, just add a variable holding the number of photos and check in the while condition:

```
$photo = 1;
$ext = '.jpg';
$numberOfPhotos = 100;

while($photo <= $numberOfPhotos) {

    echo '<a href="highslide/images/large/08/'.$photo.$ext.'" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">';

    $photo++;

}
```

Comment: You are right, I just copied the question code without checking it :)

Answer (score 2):

Heavily abbreviated code:

```
$pics = array("001","002",etc..);

foreach ($pics as $pic)
{
  echo '<a...' . $pic . '..>';
}
```

This should demonstrate the principle involved; adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The structure you use is almost correct. You just have to add a way to stop the while() loop you use. The while loop will loop until the condition within his parentheses is false.
Like Davide did. He used a maximum number to stop the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$total_photo = 20; // set total number of photo
$photo_url = "highslide/images/large/08/photo"; // set the default photo url
$photo_ext = ".jpg";

for($i = 1; $i <= $total_photo; $i++):
?>

<a href="<?php echo $photo_url . $i . $photo_ext; ?>" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
Photo <?php echo $i; ?>
</a>

<?php endfor; ?>
```

Its better if you just inline the php code to html so that its more readable